# hiding the cordova in app browser not working

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser, cordova-3.5

I need to open a page with in app browser in the background.
My cordova version is  3.5.0-0.2.6 .
And the code I'm using for test is (website name changed) :

```
<script>var ref = window.open("http://google.com/", "_blank", "hidden=yes");</script>
```

But unfortunately it shows the page .
I really don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On what device are you testing? What version of the cordova inappbrowser are you using ?
I've tested the command on my Samsung Galaxy S4 and it worked perfect.

Make sure that the cordova plugin for the inappbrowser is installed. For testing you can debug you app with Safari / Chrome and enter the window.open command into the console

EDIT:

I found out that the problem is, that you open the inappbrowser before the deviceready event is called. I highly recommend to start every cordovafunction after device ready was fired.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
            var ref = window.open("http://kghaz.ir/", "_blank", "hidden=yes");
            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function () {
                alert("Hi");
            });
        });
        
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        hi !
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: My phone is Galaxy S4 and here is the link to my test :
http://kghaz.ir/problem34/browserinapp.zip

Comment: Are you sure about what you wrote? I copy & paste and nothing happens

Comment: Yes, I am. Tested it on my on device. This Snippet works with the basic cordova setup with the InAppbrowser plugin installed.